# Delete a table row from Json using node and jQuery (No database)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I am trying to figure out how to delete a field from a Json array on click of a delete button. I am quite new at this and can't seem to figure out how to achieve this.  Here is what a simple table that pulls the data from a JSON file looked like:

[image: A simple table that pulls the data from a JSON file]

Here is the code:

```js
$(".task_box").on("click", function(evt){ 
    $("#task_table").show();
    $.getJSON("db.json", function(data) { 
      $.each(data, function(key,value) {
        console.log("Get Json data worked");
        task = data;
        var row = $('<tr><td>'  + task.box1[0].taskName+ '</td><td>'
                                + task.box1[0].time + '</td><td>'
                                + task.box1[0].location + '</td><td>' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button>')
        $('#task_table').append(row);
  });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="tasks_list">
                  <table id="task_table" class="tableStyle" >
                      <tr>
                        <th>Task Name</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Location</th>  
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                  </div>
               </div>
        </div>
```

I need to somehow update and delete table content with node, can anyone help me achieve this? Also is there a better way to fetch my array? This does not run too well for me.

I have been learning Node for about less than a week and I really can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onClick for each button you can just set each button with a class say "delete", bind the event to the table and delete the closest tr using jquery.

First change:

```
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button>'
```

to

```
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning delete">Delete</button>'
```

and then bind it to the table

```
$('table').on('click','tr a.delete',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Avoid giving unique ids to each button and calling `$("#id").remove();` as that increases the number of event handlers and is unnecessary for your use case.